# jQuery Insert After Callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This doesn't work:

```
$block.insertAfter(form);

$('.date', $block).datetime({
     userLang: 'en',
    americanMode: true
});
```

but this does:

```
$block.insertAfter(form);

window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('.date', $block).datetime({
        userLang: 'en',
        americanMode: true
    });
}, 1000);
```

`datetime()` is a plugin that I am attaching to an input element with with class `date`. Obviously #1 doesn't work because that element still isn't available in the DOM, waiting 1 second works. But it's hacky. How can I extend jQuery to accept a call back for the `insertAfter()` method or some other way?

Comment: `.promise` and [`.done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Comment: And what if you first call .datetime() and then insertAfter() ? I mean create the form detached from the DOM, then call datetime on it and insert to DOM.

Comment: How does #1 not work? It should be available in the DOM as soon as it's inserted. `insertAfter` is synchronous, so as soon as you insert `$block` after the `form`, it is available. And running the `.datetime` method after should be enough. Waiting 1 second (or any time) shouldn't matter. Am I missing something? What if you used `$block.insertAfter(form).find('.date').datetime({});`? What is `form`? I'm wondering if it is a reference to a dynamically created jQuery object (`$("<form>")`), or a reference to a DOM element (`$("form.class1")`).

Comment: if the element isn't in the DOM, you're missing your `$(document).ready(...)` handler.

Comment: I agree that there's no reason #1 shouldn't work. It would be nice to see a demo, otherwise I'm going to have to vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in the document-ready incantation:

```
$(function() {
    $block.insertAfter(form);

    $('.date', $block).datetime({
         userLang: 'en',
        americanMode: true
    });
});
```

And make sure this occurs *after* the datetime library is loaded. That is, this `<script>` tag should be after the `<script src="datetime.js">`. And make sure the `async` attribute is not set on the `<script>` tags.